# randomly shuffle 3d numpy array on specific axis

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have loaded 66 csv files, each containing a time series of 5000 time steps and three features with the following code:

```
rms = glob(sims_dir+"/rms*.csv")
df = [pd.read_csv(f).values for f in rms]
data = np.asarray(df)
```

```
data.shape
(66, 5004, 3)
```

Here my first axis of size 66 are my 66 unique time series. I would like to shuffle my array so that my first dimension (66) is of random order, but aren't exactly sure of the best way to do this... an alternative approach could be to load each csv randomly from its directory but I was wondering how this could be achieved in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.random.shuffle(data)`. This function is dedicated for this task. See  [np.random.shuffle](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)

Comment: Thanks, but does this only suffle with respect to the first dimension? i want the order of the second and third to be maintained.

Comment: Ahh "Multi-dimensional arrays are only shuffled along the first axis" thank you!